# Disabling an object from viewport and render simultaneously?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, visibility

I'm wondering if theres an option im not seeing of toggling an object off/on in both viewports and rendering?  Im a concept artist so i do a lot of iteration with duplicate objects, and its frustrating to render a scene i'm happy with, wait for the render to load, and then see that an object whose visibility was turnned off in the viewport is still turned on in the render.  I would love a single toggle button in the Scene Outliner that disables/enables an object both renders and viewports simultaneously.  Or maybe a way to link the action of disabling in viewport to disabling in render?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to vote for the feature and check comments which recommend workarounds: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/cZgbbc/?sorting=hot

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning scripting and tried to make a script for what seems simple. But couldn't find basic info that would help with turning off rendering for selected objects.

So my simple suggestion is to make a Collection and called it something like "No_Vis_Rend" and turn off the Visibility and Rendering for the collection.

Then once you need to hide certain objects, select them and press "m" then find the :No_VisRend" collection click to put them in and boop they will not be visible nor rendered.